# Add row number column to jquery datatables

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I want jQuery datatables to automatically create row number column in the first column like datagrid in VB.

It looks like this:

[image]

Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: how are you loading datatables? show some code

Comment: What you need, is just to count the result(either in json or array) then itterate it to generate a sequenced number and build it along side with other result data.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just define an empty column in aoColumns.

Then in fnRowCallback function you just edit the column how you like. This callback is run every time new row is created.

Basicly if your first column has the row number, you could just do this in fnRowCallback:

```
var index = iDisplayIndex +1;
$('td:eq(0)',nRow).html(index);
return nRow;
```

Comment: thx, i have tried it and it was a success :D

now, how do i can make the first coloumn not sortable??

Comment: oh yeah, it seems the method was success but when i change page number in datables, the row number is still from 1, how to make it continous number till the last page??

Comment: Oh, so then you want to use the: iDisplayIndexFull :)

Comment: When I applied this, every page started from 1.

Comment: @CsabToth Read the comment before yours

Answer (score 73):

Just write a render function:

```
{
    "data": "id",
    render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
        return meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's it.Nice & Clean (;

Comment: This sounded like the nicest solution, but as soon as I sort by a column the numbers get mangled

Answer (score 4):

As I commented, neither @Pehmolelu (each consecutive page started from 1) nor @Tao Wang's (when I sorted by a column the order numebrs got mangled) answer was working for me. I had to go with what the DataTables's Index Column advice was: https://datatables.net/examples/api/counter_columns.html

Note that in my case the column configuration was coming down through an API call of my webapp server (and sometimes I have row counters, sometimes don't), there were 3 system columns before this counter column, hence the column index is 3, but you need to adjust it to fit your needs.

```
t.on('order.dt search.dt', function () {
    t.column(3, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
        cell.innerHTML = i+1;
    });
}).draw();
```

Also, if your solution is not as complex as mine the link above also shows how you add that column in an unsortable + unsearchable way (again you need to adjust the column index to your needs):

```
var t = $('#example').DataTable({
    "columnDefs": [{
        "searchable": false,
        "orderable": false,
        "targets": 3
    }],
    "order": [[4, 'asc']]
});
```

There's also a plugin you may want to utilize instead of your own code.

Comment: Can you provide a sample on live.datatables.net ?

Comment: @Julius Not at the moment

Answer (score 2):

fnRowCallback in the config.
Use iDisplayIndexFull instead of iDisplayIndex. Otherwise it shows the row of the displayed tabled (without paging)

```
$('#myTable').DataTable({
    "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
        $('td:eq(0)', nRow).html(iDisplayIndexFull +1);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an another new solution which works with Datatable 1.10.

It has worked for me through sorts, searches, and page length changes. Here is my solution:

Briefly discussed in here: https://datatables.net/examples/api/counter_columns.html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var t = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "columnDefs": [ {
            "searchable": false,
            "orderable": false,
            "targets": 0
        } ],
        "order": [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
    } );
                
    t.on( 'draw.dt', function () {
    var PageInfo = $('#example').DataTable().page.info();
         t.column(0, { page: 'current' }).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
            cell.innerHTML = i + 1 + PageInfo.start;
        } );
    } );
} );
```