# How to insert serial number in jquery datatable using jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(function() {
    var oAllLinksTable = $("#mydatatable").dataTable({
      "bProcessing": false,
      "bServerSide": true,
      "sAjaxSource": "/myreports/data?Id=" + id,
      "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
      "bDestroy": true
    });
  }); 
< /script>
```

My table as follows

```
 <table id="headertagstable" style="width: 100%;" class="grid-table04 margin-b-20">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="10%" align="left" valign="middle">
        SI No
      </th>
      <th width="40%" align="left" class="black-link-first" valign="middle">
        Name
      </th>
      <th width="25%" align="left" valign="middle">
        Date
      </th>
      <th width="25%" align="left" valign="middle">
        Place
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

All works fine except serial number. How can I add serial number using jquery ?

Comment: rather than inserting more code provide description along with code to understand the problem

Comment: in my how can i insert serial number using jquery i try to implement   "aoColumnDefs": [{"bSortable": true, "bSearchable": true,
  "fnRender": function (oObj) {//here how can i generate serial number? and use return the serial number }"aTargets": [0]
}

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you can try following

```
"fnRowCallback" : function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex){
                $("td:first", nRow).html(iDisplayIndex +1);
               return nRow;
            },
```

refer http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/2169/adding-and-deleting-rows-with-row-numbers/p1

another solution i just found on stackoverflow itself is as follow:

```
var index = iDisplayIndex +1;
$('td:eq(0)',nRow).html(index);
return nRow;
```

refer [Add row number column to jquery datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871198/add-row-number-coloumn-to-jquery-datatables)

**Updated :** 
Just tweak the fnRowCallback function to get serial numbers correctly with paginations

```
    "fnRowCallback" : function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex){      
                          var oSettings = oAllLinksTable.fnSettings();
                           $("td:first", nRow).html(oSettings._iDisplayStart+iDisplayIndex +1);
                           return nRow;
                },
```

Comment: hi hemanth by using this the serial no always starts with 1 in case next 10 values are selected .i need to show next 10 as 11 to 20

Answer (score 9):

Here is the simple answer. Use datatable render method.

Example :

```
var i = 1;

$("#myTable1").dataTable().fnDestroy();


$('#myTable1').DataTable({

  ajax: base_url + 'specific_function',

  columns: [

    {
      "render": function(data, type, full, meta) {
        return i++;
      }
    },
    {
      "data": "col_2_data"
    },
    {
      "data": "col_3_data"
    },
    {
      "render": function(data, type, full, meta) {
        return '<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="editBUT(' + full.id + ')">EDIT</button>';
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: _Done .Thank you_

Answer (score 9):

just add the following code

```
"columns": [
        {
        "title": "Serial",
        render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
        return meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart + 1;
        }
        }
       ],
```

Answer (score 7):

I have solved using following code. The code works fine for me.

```
"rowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
     var oSettings = this.fnSettings ();
     $("td:first", nRow).html(oSettings._iDisplayStart+iDisplayIndex +1);
     return nRow;
},
```

Use `this.fnSettings ();` instead of `oAllLinksTable.fnSettings();` will solve the issue.

refer https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/5316/strange-behavior-of-fnsettings

Comment: This works with pagination... Thankx bro... but while you click sort ascending or descending, its not changing like 10,9,8,7,....

Answer (score 4):

I've solved using the following code. The code works fine with pagination.

```
    var dt = $('#table-id').DataTable({
         ...,
         "createdRow": function (row, data, index) {
              var info = dt.page.info();
              $('td', row).eq(0).html(index + 1 + info.page * info.length);
          },
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Just tweak the fnRowCallback function to get serial numbers correctly with paginations

```
    "fnRowCallback" : function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex){      
                          var oSettings = oAllLinksTable.fnSettings();
                           $("td:first", nRow).html(oSettings._iDisplayStart+iDisplayIndex +1);
                           return nRow;
                },
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#users').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: "",
    columns: [{
          data: id,
          render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
               return meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart + 1;
          }
    }]
});
```

Comment: render used with `columnDefs` not with `columns`

Answer (score 1):

when we use **Server Side Rendering,** One of the Easy & Best Way for Display **Auto Increment Sr No.** instead of table row id... I used **"Laravel Yajra DataTable"**

simply use **return meta.row + 1;** .

see Below Example Code

```
columns: [
    {data: 'SrNo',
       render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
            return meta.row + 1;
       }
    },
    .... //your Code(Other Columns)
 ]
```

Or You can also Use like this

```
columns: [
        {data: 'SrNo',
           render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                return meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart + 1;
           }
        },
        .... //your Code(Other Columns)
     ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The continuation of serial number breaks when next pagination is clicked, using **iDisplayIndex** the following code:

```
"fnRowCallback" : function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex){
      $("td:first", nRow).html(iDisplayIndex +1);
      return nRow;
 },
```

instead you can use **aData** for displaying continuation of serial number:

```
"fnRowCallback" : function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex){
      $("td:first", nRow).html(aData.DT_RowIndex);
      return nRow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"fnDrawCallback": function(oSettings) {
      var count=0;
      $('#myTable').find('tr').each(function() {
        $(this).find('td').eq(0).before('<td>' + count + '</td>');
        count++;
      });
    }
```

Comment: Code-only answers may solve the problem but they are much more useful if you explain how they solve it. Community requires theory as well as code both to understand your answer fully.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an another new solution which works with Datatable 1.10.

Briefly discussed in here: https://datatables.net/examples/api/counter_columns.html

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var t = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "columnDefs": [ {
            "searchable": false,
            "orderable": false,
            "targets": 0
        } ],
        "order": [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
    } );
                
    t.on( 'draw.dt', function () {
    var PageInfo = $('#example').DataTable().page.info();
         t.column(0, { page: 'current' }).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
            cell.innerHTML = i + 1 + PageInfo.start;
        } );
    } );
} );
```