# How to add row number on table genareted by JQuery DataTable with server side datasource

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I use JQuery [DataTable](http://www.datatables.net) to bind and show my data. However, I can't add row number to generated grid from client side. Here my code:

### HTML

```
<table id="applications_list" class="table table-bordered datagrid">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo __('No.'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo __('Application Code'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo __('Application Name'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo __('Created By'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo __('Created Date'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo __('Action'); ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### Javascript

```
$('#applications_list').dataTable({
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "bFilter": true,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "sAjaxSource": config.siteURL  + "/applications/ajax_index",
    "sServerMethod": "POST",
    "aoColumns": [
        { "mData": null, "bSortable": false },
        { "mData": "app_applicationcode",  "sName": "app_applicationcode" },
        { "mData": "app_applicationname", "sName": "app_applicationname" },
        { "mData": "app_createdby", "sName": "app_createdby" },
        { "mData": "app_createddate", "sName": "app_createddate" },
        { "mData": "app_applicationcode", "bSortable": false, "mRender": function(data) {
            return '<a href="' + config.siteURL + '/applications/delete/' + data + '" class="confirm_delete"><i class="">x</i></a>' 
        }},
   ],
    "aaSorting": [[ 0, 'asc' ]],
});
```

I read documentation [here](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/counter_column.html), but it won't work. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: why can't you add it to data server side? You have the row start...or else wouldn't be able to set limit in db lookup

Comment: Yes, that the solutions, but I just want to add it on client side.

Comment: likely find what you need in  `.fnSettings()`

Comment: I don't see `.fnSettings()` will solve the problem. Can you point me a sample?

Comment: look through it, it's a huge object, should have your paging posiiton. Then use code you linked to. far easier to do this on server

Answer (score 15):

Best solution:

```
"columns": [

    { "data": null,"sortable": false, 
       render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                 return meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart + 1;
                }  
    },
......
]
```

Comment: Why is it the best ? Please add more context to your answer

Answer (score 6):

For DataTables 1.10.4,

```
"fnCreatedRow": function (row, data, index) {
            $('td', row).eq(0).html(index + 1);
        }
```

Comment: Partially works, it simply adds the numbers, but does not work with pagination when doing it from a server-side.

Comment: Not worth with pagination , its start with again 0

Answer (score 6):

Add following code in "fnRowCallback":

**For Datatables 1.10**

```
"fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
     var info = $(this).DataTable().page.info();
     $("td:nth-child(1)", nRow).html(info.start + iDisplayIndex + 1);
     return nRow;
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

The guide from [official documentation](https://datatables.net/examples/api/counter_columns.html) didn't work on server side tables. The best answer I can get is from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6871669/1492665) (from another question), just to write a render function:

```
{
    "data": "id",
    render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
        return meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart + 1;
    }
}
```

Go upvote that answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since none of the solutions here worked for me, here is my solution for a server-side.

1. add the extra `<th></th>` in your table, this is to mark where the number is to be inserted.
2. add the following right after initiating the table, the same way you would add `"ajax": {"url":"somepage"},`

   **"fnCreatedRow": function (row, data, index) {
    var info = table.page.info();
    var value = index+1+info.start;
           $('td', row).eq(0).html(value);
       },**

3.At the location where the variables are defined for the table columns, add this column { "data": null,"sortable": false  },
so it looks like this:

```
"columns": [
{ "data": null,"sortable": false  },
......]
```

4. To get rid of the sorting icon (up-down arrow), select the second column by adding , `"order": [[ 1, 'asc' ]]`, the same way you would add "ajax"....

Comment: I try to follow your code but I got this "ReferenceError: table is not defined" error.. **EDIT : I resolve the error, just add var table = $('#datatable').DataTable({....**

Comment: @Mikey Please suggest the changes in the answer, and I will approve it, so other people do not get the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible by make use of *fnPagingInfo* api in the *rowCallback* to get the page and the display length and use it to calculate the row number like this:

For DataTables < 1.10

```
$('#example').dataTable({
  "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
     var page = this.fnPagingInfo().iPage;
     var length = this.fnPagingInfo().iLength;
     var index = = (page * length + (iDisplayIndex +1));
     $('td:eq(0)', nRow).html(index);
  }
});
```

For DataTables == 1.10

```
$('#example').dataTable({
  "rowCallback": function( row, data, iDisplayIndex ) {
     var info = this.api.page.info();
     var page = info.page;
     var length = info.length;
     var index = = (page * length + (iDisplayIndex +1));
     $('td:eq(0)', row).html(index);
  }
});
```

NOTE: for DataTables < 1.10, you have to add the [fnPageInfo.js](https://github.com/DataTables/Plugins/tree/master/api/fnPagingInfo.js) script to your page

Comment: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '='

Answer (score 1):

[Official solution from DataTable](https://datatables.net/examples/api/counter_columns.html):

```
table.on( 'order.dt search.dt', function () {
    table.column(0, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
        cell.innerHTML = i+1;
    } );
} ).draw();
```

Comment: But for server side processing, its working fine on initial load and on sorting but when we search any item, it places [object Object] instead of s.no.

Answer (score 1):

when we use **Server Side Rendering,** One of the Easy & Best Way for Display **Auto Increment Sr No.** instead of table row id... I used **"Laravel Yajra DataTable"**

simply use **return meta.row + 1;** .

see Below Example Code

```
columns: [
    {data: 'SrNo',
       render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
            return meta.row + 1;
       }
    },
    .... //your Code(Other Columns)
 ]
```

Or You can also Use like this

```
columns: [
        {data: 'SrNo',
           render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                return meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart + 1;
           }
        },
        .... //your Code(Other Columns)
     ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `<?php echo __('No.'); ?>` is the primary key from database you can use `columnDefs` to add the key as row number to each cell of a row like this

```
"columnDefs": [{
    "targets": '_all',
    "createdCell": function(cell, cellData, rowData, rowIndex, colIndex) {
        $(cell).attr({'data-pk': rowData[0]});
    }
}]
```

Where `rowData[0]` will be the primary key value.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `return meta.row + 1` this inside render function. For Example.

```js
{
  data: "",
  render: function(rec, type, row, meta) {
    return meta.row + 1;
  }
}
```